# How to wait until component is fully loaded on Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, components

I need to run a script when a Component is fully loaded.  Is there a way to do that, like ajaxStart() and .ajaxStop() on jQuery?

I am trying to add my code on ngAfterViewInit(); but sometimes the component is not fully loaded when that function is called.

Thank you so much :)

My code is as follows:

```
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { };
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "./assets/js/my-script-to-run.js";
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
    }
 }
```

Comment: *"sometimes the compoenent is not fully loaded"* - how do you judge it's not fully loaded?

Comment: sometimes the response is not faster, and the result is an empty page until everything is loaded, the thing is, exit a wait to listen when the response is ready to consume as well?

Comment: So you want to do something when both the component is loaded and when the response from the ajax request has arrived?

Comment: yes @GünterZöchbauer this is correct.